# Is my guitar action too high or is the bridge too high?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

Guitar action pics : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF5jS.jpg

I've been trying to play barre chords for a few weeks now but i could never make the G string to play, also I feel like im putting to much pressure to play the barre chords then is required. I just wanted to know if it's just improper technique or is my action too high.

Comment: At which fret are you having trouble?

Answer (score 6):

Action, to an extent, is due to the height of the bridge. Which does look like it could be lower. It's way higher than the bridges on my guitars, but I do like as low an action as possible. The strings look like maybe .011 - 054 ish, so again, there's not a lot in your favour for learning to play barre chords. They are heavy-ish and will present more tension making them difficult to hold down. G string problem may be because it's wound, and will be tight compared with a plain G, although wound is commonplace on acoustics.

If you don't want to change to lighter strings, tune down a tone. It will make the strings easier to barre. but the bridge needs lowering. If it's a fixed bridge with no adjustment, it's a job that can be done, but not then undone! Go too low, and there will be problems.

Comment: The strings are 0.011-0.05 light gauge as per the packet.

Comment: I wasn't far out! .050 is heavier than I use, and will be fairly tight for a beginner learning to barre.

Comment: Is the relief alright for the guitar? Would lowering or increasing relief help? I live far away from a guitar shop  and it would take almost a day to travel to and fro

Comment: Relief doesn't look too bad. I'd start by lowering the bridge, until one string starts to rattle on a fret (any fret, try all), then raise a little.Increasing relief will make the problem worse!

Answer (score 2):

The action will be a result of the height of the nut, the height of the bridge, and the amount of relief in the neck.

Your action lower down the neck does look high to me. It's hard for me to tell if that's due to the bridge height, or also due to the amount of neck relief.

If you can find a reasonably-priced local tech or music shop, I'd suggest taking it to them for a check-up.

Answer (score 1):

Get a second bridge and make it slight lower than the one on it. Than replace the first bridge with that one. If it helps great if not you can put the other one back on. IMPORTANT; You just want to replace the ivory part of the bridge - not the wood part. You can find the part at a local music store. Anything else would be too risky by a non-luthier.

Comment: is the saddle ( the white part) attached to the wooden part through glue or is it just held in place by the string tension ?

Comment: It is usually not glued or is lightly glued just try to gentle pry it out. I've never saw one glued in, but you never know for sure.